# Question about Nyquist sampling - filtering of high image copies

Tags: sampling, nyquist

Suppose I sample an audio signal with a sampling frequency > twice the highest audio frequency.

ie, the frequency transform of the sampled signal looks like the image on top here, where there is no overlap of copies:

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem#/media/File:ReconstructFilter.png]

Also, suppose that all the high image copies are outside the audible range. Now is there any need for a brickwall filter in this situation? I'd think it was unnecessary since the audible part of the original and sampled signal are identical. As a specific example, say we sampled a signal at 96 kHz. Now is there a need for any filtering to remove high image copies? Thanks.

Comment: in a sense, your finite hearing range becomes the lowpass filter that filters out the images.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, yes. That's what I was thinking also. But I'm wondering if there are some unforeseen side-effects to having those images there.

Comment: BTW, that graphic was done by me circa 2 decades ago, back when I could haunt Wikipedia under my own name.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, very nice graphic.

Comment: [My version of the Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem&oldid=70713137) was a lot better, for pedagogical purposes than what that article became.  Now I am banned from Wikipedia, so I can only edit anonymously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your scenario where an audio analog signal having nonzero spectral components from zero Hz to, say, 15 kHz, is sampled at a rate of 96 kHz the separation between the blue and green curves (in your linked web page picture) will be larger than the separation shown in the picture.

To answer your question of: "I'm wondering if there are some unforeseen side-effects to having those images there.", the answer is "No". And I say "No" because there is no spectral overlap of the sampled x[n] signal's blue and green curves, thus no "aliasing" errors have been caused by sampling the original analog signal at 96 kHz.

Now if you were to perform some processing on the discrete x[n] sampled signal that results in some sort of frequency translation (such AM modulation, or discrete signal decimation) causing overlap of the blue and green curves then you'll be introducing errors in your new "processed" discrete signal. The bottom line here is well-known; For any discrete lowpass signal the sample rate must be greater than twice the highest-frequency spectral component.

On that linked web page the page's author wrote: "A brick-wall low-pass filter, H(f), removes the images, leaves the original spectrum, X(f), and recovers the original signal from its samples." That sentence, without further explanation, is super misleading! There is *NO* digital filter that will eliminate the spectral images (the green curves) from a discrete signal sequence.ㅤ

Comment: *//"That sentence, without further explanation, is super misleading!"//* Really??  How is the sentence, as it is, misleading?

Comment: *//" There is NO digital filter that will eliminate the spectral images (the green curves) from a discrete signal sequence."//*

Where does that sentence say anything about a **digital** filter?   Even so, as long as we're willing to put in enough MIPS and tolerate enough throughput delay, in upsampling, a digital filter can get arbitrarily close to that ideal brick wall and we audio interpolationists do that with a variety of tools `firpm()`, `firls()`, `kaiser().*sinc()`.

Comment: All discrete signal sequences have spectral "replica6tions" centered at integer multiples of the sequence's sample rate (ie., the green spectral curves). What I'm saying is: There is *NO* digital signal processing that we can perform on a discrete sequence that will eliminate (attenuate) those spectral replications.

Comment: Richard, every discrete-time system has repeated images.  But you can **still** using DSP, emulate a continuous-time filter with a continuous-time finite impulse response. A simple idea that I have always had, but got published by [Smith and Gossett](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem&oldid=70713137) is a polyphase FIR interpolation with a very high upsample ratio (I think $r=512$ is about right) and then linear interpolation remaining to make the impulse response continuous-time.

Comment: Before linear interpolation, you have images at every $512 \times f_\text{s}$ but those images still have width of $\pm\frac{f_\text{s}}{2}$ from their center.  Then linear interpolation ***kills*** those images quite well with an upsample ratio of 512.  It's not a misleading sentence at all.  Especially for explaining where the sinc interpolation comes from in reconstruction.  That refutes your claim: *//"There is NO digital signal processing that we can perform on a discrete sequence that will eliminate (attenuate) those spectral replications."//*

Comment: @Robert You seem to be saying you can design a digital interpolation filter (whose input is a sequence of discrete samples) that has a "continuous-time" impulse response. If the time-domain impulse response of your filter is a sequence of discrete samples then it seems to me that this impulse response cannot be considered "continuous-time". What am I missing here? Can you elaborate on exactly what your phrase "continuous-time" means?

Comment: *//"You seem to be saying you can design a digital interpolation filter (whose input is a sequence of discrete samples) that has a "continuous-time" impulse response."//*--- Yup. $$ $$ *//"Can you elaborate on exactly what your phrase "continuous-time" means?"//* --- Exactly what Oppenhiem and Schafer mean with *"continuous-time"* (as opposed to *"discrete-time"*).  It means that the $t$ in $h(t)$ is a real, continuous variable.

Comment: I am also saying that the caption I gave that figure way back in 2006 or 2007: *"A brick-wall low-pass filter, H(f), removes the images, leaves the original spectrum, X(f), and recovers the original signal from its samples."*, I am saying that this caption is ***precisely*** correct and not misleading in any way.  And I am asking you, Richard, to spell out what is *"super misleading"* about it.

Comment: @Robert: I just now realized that you’re the author of the original linked “Nyquist” wiki web page. (I see that Peter K deleted the page’s URL link and pasted the wiki figure in the poster’s question’s text.) I also think I now see why you and I are disagreeing here.

Regarding your “brick-wall lowpass filter” sentence, in my Answer’s text I said that sentence needs “further explanation” to be correct.

Comment: At the top of the figure you show the spectral magnitude of a discrete sequence obtained by sampling an arbitrary lowpass analog signal. You show the analog signal’s spectrum with a blue curve, and you show two spectral replications with two green curves. So far so good.

Then your “brick-wall lowpass filter” sentence says we can filter the discrete sequence to eliminate the spectral replications leaving only the blue-curve spectrum. We both know that no such digital filter is possible.

Comment: What I believe the wiki’s figure’s caption should say is:

“If we convert the sampled discrete sequence to an analog signal (using an A/D converter) and pass that analog signal through an ideal analog brick-wall low-pass filter we can produce an analog lowpass signal having a spectrum equal to that of the original sampled analog signal.”

I hope what I’ve written here makes sense.

Comment: Shoot. In my last "comment" the phrase "A/D converter" should be "D/A converter".

Comment: *//"We both know that no such digital filter is possible."//* --- Yes, but we both know we can get arbitrarily close to the brickwall if we're willing to put in enough MIPS **and** accept the throughput delay.  I see that you took out the word *"(attenuate)"* leaving only *"eliminate"*.  So, at that strict place, I cannot disagree, but the caption to the figure is still accurate, ***particularly*** for the application at the Wikipedia page about the Nyquist-Shannon sampling and reconstruction theorem.

Comment: -1 on an answer I agree with for lack of -1 from others on contradicting them.

Comment: Audio's real-world and "nothing real-world is bandlimited", and it's also "timelimited so can't be bandlimited", something others are quick and vocal to remark, unless it's a specific speaker. Part of "intellectual apathy, discrimination". First and maybe last such comment I'll ever make.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon, what does your sentence "-1 on an answer I agree with for lack of -1 from others on contradicting them." mean?


Regarding this thread, I’m merely saying that the impulse responses of all digital filters are sequences of discrete-time samples. Robert keeps implying that a digital filter can have an analog (continuous-time) impulse response.

Comment: It means I've got arguments, no support, and downvotes for saying what you said, and if I wrote this answer I question it'd be +2 -0. I detailed what substance-wise in my second comment.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Thanks for the clarification. I'm still learning DSP so, as I said, I can't conceive of a digital filter that has an analog impulse response and produces an analog output. If you have the time could you teach me how such a digital filter operates? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not commenting on your discussion with RBJ. My exact complaint is, OP says "audio", which implies "timelimited", which cannot be "bandlimited", so the premise of the question is flawed, which you don't address. I agree with not addressing this, but others do not, and they didn't bother to correct you, yet they have corrected me in the past.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon, OK now I see. You're concerned with a subject that's not directly related to the primary topic of the thread (which was, Can a digital filter have an analog output?). If I said something incorrect in this thread I was just wondering if you might be willing to "straighten me out". I'm always willing to learn.

Comment: My concern is with the question's opening sentence, and your response, _"no "aliasing" errors have been caused by sampling the original analog signal"_. If it's audio, it's aliased. If going by how ardently it's treated elsewhere, this isn't "side-technicality", and at minimum there should be a remark to reword or clarify the sentence - same with when one oversimplifies in another context. -- Regardless... upon further thought of all factors, maybe it's not as severe as I thought - I didn't pick a good case to make example of. I'm unsure what's right here, I'll just note I'd not `-1` a `<=1`.

Comment: To rephrase and amend, I've overestimated the extent of others' need to comment on this post. I stand by there being double standards in other cases however. And I think it's more honest to remark directly that you're speaking for others instead of directing it at me, since I said I agree with this answer and its simplification. @OlliNiemitalo

Comment: Locked by system until edited, didn't feel compelled enough to edit or remark it. But I'll remark it now - or more. @OlliNiemitalo

Comment: I enjoy discussing DSP concepts with DSP aficionados such as you guys. For me, there is no "downside", no disadvantage, to such discussions.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I wrote my above "I enjoy ..." comment and then I wanted to add a few words to my comment. But this poorly-designed website doesn't permit editing a comment after five minutes. I wanted to say, it appears that something about this thread is philosophically, and personally, troubling for you. I don't know exactly what troubled you. But I must say that in the past I have also been personally troubled by DSP threads on the Internet. So don't worry OverLordGoldDragon, everything will be OK.

Comment: @RichardLyons I have no quarrel with you or your answer. It's things that get under most people's radars but afflict both the general audience and some of network's participants, but also things hard to prove, and I've not helped the cause by picking a bad example.